# Where are attributes defined for PrimeFaces 6.x UIComponents?

Tags: primefaces

I'm browsing the [PrimeFaces 6.1 source at GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/java/).

The components only seem to have a renderer class and no component class. For example, the [`OutputLabelRenderer` references 
the `OutputLabel`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/outputlabel/OutputLabelRenderer.java#L54), but the `OutputLabel` class is nowhere to be found. I expected it to be in the same folder as the renderer (as there was no import).

I did find this [template file](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/java-templates/org/primefaces/component/outputlabel/OutputLabelTemplate.java) though. So it looks like it is generated somehow.

Where can I find the attributes for a PrimeFaces component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the `pom.xml` I've found this [plugin](https://github.com/primefaces/maven-jsf-plugin):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jsf-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-ui</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <uri>http://primefaces.org/ui</uri>
                <shortName>p</shortName>
                <templatesDir>src/main/java-templates</templatesDir>
                <componentConfigsDir>target/resources-maven-jsf/ui</componentConfigsDir>
                <standardFacesConfig>src/main/resources-maven-jsf/standard-faces-config.xml</standardFacesConfig>
                <standardFaceletsTaglib>src/main/resources-maven-jsf/standard-facelets-taglib.xml</standardFaceletsTaglib>
                <standardTLD>src/main/resources-maven-jsf/standard-tld.xml</standardTLD>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate-components</goal>
                <goal>generate-facelets-taglib</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        ...
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The definition (including the attributes) are located in the `/src/main/resources-maven-jsf/ui/` folder. For examplate [`outputLabel.xml`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/resources-maven-jsf/ui/outputLabel.xml).

You can also download the sources JAR from Maven. It will include the component code. For example:

```
/*
 * Generated, Do Not Modify
 */
/*
 * Copyright 2009-2013 PrimeTek.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.primefaces.component.outputlabel;

import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLabel;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.el.MethodExpression;
import javax.faces.render.Renderer;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceDependencies;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceDependency;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils;

@ResourceDependencies({

})
public class OutputLabel extends HtmlOutputLabel {


    public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "org.primefaces.component.OutputLabel";
    public static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "org.primefaces.component";
    public static final String DEFAULT_RENDERER = "org.primefaces.component.OutputLabelRenderer";

    public enum PropertyKeys {

        indicateRequired;

        String toString;

        PropertyKeys(String toString) {
            this.toString = toString;
        }

        PropertyKeys() {}

        public String toString() {
            return ((this.toString != null) ? this.toString : super.toString());
}
    }

    public OutputLabel() {
        setRendererType(DEFAULT_RENDERER);
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    public boolean isIndicateRequired() {
        return (java.lang.Boolean) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.indicateRequired, true);
    }
    public void setIndicateRequired(boolean _indicateRequired) {
        getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.indicateRequired, _indicateRequired);
    }


    public final static String STYLE_CLASS = "ui-outputlabel ui-widget";
    public final static String REQUIRED_FIELD_INDICATOR_CLASS = "ui-outputlabel-rfi";
}
```

Comment: PrimeFaces should consider using the 'Component Development Kit' that RichFaces uses (used). Annotations on the java code instead of xml and generating xml instead of java

Comment: @Kukeltje yeah, I was looking around a bit to see what it takes to create a component library. I really dislike the fact that you need to define and use properties / attributes in the component Java, taglib XML and documentation. Annotation seem to be a good idea as a good source to generate stuff from.

Comment: I'll file an enhancement request for PF 7.0 (thought I already did something like this some time ago but cannot find it).

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't think PF will / needs to change what they've already built. I just wanted to see if I could create a new simple component library.

Comment: PF 'should' to make it more easier for other as an example for others

Comment: @Kukeltje just finished a first draft of a Maven plugin that reads compiled component classes and reads taglib info from custom annotations. Thanks for the idea :-)

Comment: You are welcome. But it's not my idea... RichFaces does it (and jpa for meta classes) and... is it in your git repo? I'd like to test it on PrimeFaces (to see how your plugin works with extended classes e.g. if it also reads annotations on them

Comment: Not yet.. I'll let you know when it's pushed to Git.

Comment: @Kukeltje long overdue: https://github.com/jepsar/starfaces-maven-plugin (still work in progress though)

Comment: But how is this related to the new PF 7 building btw?

Comment: It's not. They no longer seem to be using their maven plugin. I put it on Git for Stephan Rauh to have a look in context of a new BootFaces version.